Pairwise multiple linear regressions in a pandas dataframe
I want to perform pairwise multiple linear regressions in a pandas data frame. Specifically, I want to regress each column on each other column and provide the columns of the other dataframe as additional predictors (of no interest / covariates)
The result should be a symmetric matrix containing the slopes of the target column as values. A very similar idea is already implemented with pd.DataFrame.corr(); this method also seems quite fast for large data frames. pd.DataFrame.corr() also offers to provide a callable as a method. I first thought I could use this for multiple linear regression but this callable does not allow for more arguments inputs than just the two columns. In other words - You can only perform simple linear regression with it. What I would like to do is to have something similar fast as pd.DataFrame.corr() that allows me to compute multiple linear regression. I could of course use a for-loop with all combinations of the source and target columns as inputs but I wonder if there's a more computationally efficient approach.
Here's some example code to produce example data and to illustrate what works so far (person correlation and simple linear regression):
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Set the random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# Set the number of rows for the DataFrames
num_rows = 100

# Generate the first DataFrame with columns x1, x2, x3
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x1': np.random.randn(num_rows),  # Random normal values
    'x2': np.random.randn(num_rows),  # Random normal values
    'x3': np.random.randn(num_rows)   # Random normal values
})

# Generate the second DataFrame with columns age and gender
df_covariates = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': np.random.randint(18, 80, size=num_rows),  # Random age between 18 and 80
    'gender': np.random.choice([0,1],size=num_rows)  # Random gender choice
})

# we can use pd.DataFrame.corr() to correlate each column with each other column
corrs = df.corr()

# we can also use linear regression and return the slope
def get_slope(x, y):

    # Add a constant to the independent variable for the intercept term
    y = sm.add_constant(y)
    
    # Fit the regression model
    model = sm.OLS(x, y).fit()
    
    # Return the slope (coefficient for the independent variable y)
    slope = model.params[1]  # Index 1 corresponds to the slope
    
    return slope

slopes = df.corr(method=get_slope)

But what I would like to do is to perform this regression:
xi ~ xj + age + gender
And then return the slope for xj predictor column.

Try using pyglm.GLM(y, X, family='normal')
